# how could I swipe the page from left to right in order to go back in a webview?

Tags: react-native

In a web view,I want to swipe the page from left to right in order to go back,just like what safari did.
what should I do?

Comment: Do you have solved this question?

Comment: I know this is a long short but did any of these suggestions work for you? I am in the same issue right now. Swiping back takes me out of the webview entirely

Answer (score 7):

You can use `react-native-webview` package. And just pass `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures` prop to `WebView`:

```
 import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

    <WebView
      allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures
      ...
    />
```

Comment: But why is this not working? I am using android. When I swipe left or right, it exits the webview entirely and goes to my previous navigation stack? This is a very important feature that I need to activate

Answer (score 5):

**TL/DR:** Currently, you'll need a third party package for that. Use the [react-native-wkwebview-reborn](https://github.com/CRAlpha/react-native-wkwebview) package and set the  `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures` prop to true. Example:

`WebView.ios.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import WKWebView from 'react-native-wkwebview-reborn';

export default (props) => <WKWebView allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures {...props} />
```

`WebView.js`

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default WebView;
```

It's a drop-in replacement, so you won't need to change much code.

---

**Why:**

The `WebView` component from React Native uses [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview) under the hood, which is not recommended by Apple anymore:

[image: wkwebview]

It has worse performance and does not support a lot of features, like 3D Touch and swipe back gesture.

Join [this discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/321#issuecomment-290953001) so react native updates their core component.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a long time but I came across with the same problem and couldn't find any working solutions **for android**. So I came up with mine. Also, this post is first to show up when you google 'react native Webview swipe back', so I thought it would help more people posting my solution here.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { StyleSheet, Platform, BackHandler } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  
  const webViewRef = React.useRef();

  const onAndroidBackpress = () => {
    if (webViewRef.current) {
      webViewRef.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  return (
    <WebView
      onTouchStart={e =>  {
        if(Platform.OS === 'android'){ 
          this.touchX = e.nativeEvent.pageX; 
          this.touchY = e.nativeEvent.pageY 
        } else {
          return null
        }}
      }
      onTouchEnd={e =>  {
        if(Platform.OS === 'android' && this.touchX - e.nativeEvent.pageX < -20){
          if(this.touchY - e.nativeEvent.pageY > -20 && this.touchY - e.nativeEvent.pageY < 20){
            onAndroidBackpress()
          }
        } else {
          return null
        }}
      }
      allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures // only works with iOS
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback
      ref={webViewRef}
      style={styles.container}
      source={{ uri: "https://<yourwebsite>.com" }}
    />
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```